# SQL Server stored procedure: datetime parameter is wrong format sometimes depending on dateformat of country

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

This SQL Server stored procedure takes several parameters, and one of them is a `datetime` data type.

We've just began to localize the application in Europe, and the problem is that they're receiving this:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

I've done my reading on `datetime`, so I believe what is happening is the application is posting the date as dd/mm/yyyy to SQL Server, but since the database has a default language of English and expects mm/dd/yyyy, there is an error.

Sample input that produces error:

```
@LastUpdatedDate = N'21.01.2016 03:54:08'
```

My coworker in Europe said that when he set the default language of the database to German, the error quit occurring.

This error has not shown up in the USA/Canada, and I'm assuming that if the application **AND** SQL Server are running the same default `datetime` format, then no issues. However, we (here in USA), need to work with their application and database in Europe, so now we get the error.

Here's the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[addUser]
(
    @UserID NVARCHAR ( 50 ),
    @AccountID NVARCHAR( 50 ) = '00000000000000000000000000000000',
    @Password NVARCHAR( 50 ),
    @FirstName nvarchar(50),
    @LastName nvarchar(50),
    @Telephone nvarchar(25),
    @Mobile nvarchar(25),
    @FAX nvarchar(25),
    @EmailAddress nvarchar(50),
    @CurrentUserID nvarchar(50),
    @LastUpdatedBy nvarchar(50),
    @LastUpdatedDate datetime 
)
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO tbUsers (UserID, AccountID, Password, Status, VPID, EvalStatusID, FirstName, LastName, Telephone, Mobile, FAX, EmailAddress, LastUpdatedBy, LastUpdatedDate)
    VALUES (@UserID, @AccountID, @Password, 'A', 'PM', 'ACTIVE', @FirstName, @LastName, @Telephone, @Mobile, @FAX, @EmailAddress, @LastUpdatedBy, @LastUpdatedDate)
```

I don't have access to the application code yet, but question is:

Is there a way to catch the error and fix the `datetime` input value depending on how database is configured?

I tried using `SET DATEFORMAT dmy` before the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, but it errors out before that.

Yes, we could probably alter the application code to use a language-neutral `datetime` format, but that may not be feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

**Update:** if you're on SQL Server **2012** or newer, you could use the new `TRY_PARSE` function in T-SQL which allows you to parse strings representing dates safely. You can specify a locale to use, and if the parse doesn't work, you get back a `NULL` instead of an exception.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input NVARCHAR(100) = N'21.01.2016 03:54:08'

SELECT 
    TRY_PARSE(@input AS DATE USING 'en-gb')
```

Should return a valid `DATE` value of Jan-21, 2016 - no matter what language/locale your SQL Server is set to

Comment: Yes, this all seems unnecessarily complicated.

However, if N'21.01.2016 03:54:08' is passed as a parameter to the stored procedure, is there anything I can do at that point? Or do I need to go back in time and prevent that datetime string format from coming in?

Comment: @Jeffrey You can reformat the date string to a locale neutral format. Marc_s mentions two: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]` and `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]`. The rectangular brackets indicate optional parts. Note the space between the date part and time part in the second format. You can find these two ISO-8601 formats that are accepted by DATETIME in the [Documentation on DATETIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Comment: @Jeffrey: well, *either* you can make sure the callers will always use the ISO-8601 format which will **always work** - or then you need to do a lot more checking/processing on your end in SQL Server. What **version** of SQL Server are you on? SQL Server **2012** and newer offer methods like `PARSE` and `TRY_PARSE` which can handle a lot of that work quite nicely, and then support locales, too